# Zipping and/or transferring very large files (200+ GB) on Google Drive using Colab

Tags: google-drive-api

I've been using a script to mount two google drives on one google drive runtime to move files around, but it complains that I'm out of space when I'm moving the large files. I tried running it one file at a time and I'm still stuck on the large files...

Edit:

I use

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/drive1')
```

and

```
!apt-get install -y -qq software-properties-common module-init-tools
!add-apt-repository -y ppa:alessandro-strada/ppa 2>&1 > /dev/null
!apt-get update -qq 2>&1 > /dev/null
!apt-get -y install -qq google-drive-ocamlfuse fuse
from google.colab import auth
auth.authenticate_user()
from oauth2client.client import GoogleCredentials
creds = GoogleCredentials.get_application_default()
import getpass
!google-drive-ocamlfuse -headless -id={creds.client_id} -secret={creds.client_secret} < /dev/null 2>&1 | grep URL
vcode = getpass.getpass()
!echo {vcode} | google-drive-ocamlfuse -headless -id={creds.client_id} -secret={creds.client_secret}
!mkdir -p /drive2
!google-drive-ocamlfuse /drive2
```

to mount the two drives, then I tried a simple copy:

```
!cp -vru /drive2/folder /drive1/folder
```

but it kept failing due to the drive space. I also tried splitting the files using zip (without copying it to the google colab file system first), so all the data stays in the google drive

```
! zip -r -db -dc -Z bzip2 -T -m -s 5g /drive1/zipfilename /drive1/folder
```

but I still kept running out of space.

Comment: Are you out of space?

Comment: @mjwills: no. i just want to move the files to a different google drive

Comment: @DaImTo is it, tho? the solution is probably running some bash/python script in google colab.

Comment: @vardonir if its a script then please edit your question include your code and describe any issues you are having with your solution.